# Shell Script to read key value response

Tags: shell, key

I looking to access each key and value from following response.

[image]

Key                 Value

---

**accessor            n/a**

How to access the rule to get the array values? ( due to format change, I have updated one key value pair. please let me know if any more details required.

Comment: When the response is an image, it will be very hard. What did you try?

Comment: Is that the only possible output format that your mystery command can output?

Comment: Key                 Value
---                 -----
accessor            n/a
creation       1664279392
creation        1h